# How to fetch from database according to form input in ebean java play framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2, ebean, playframework-2.1

i have a form with two tables one for drivers and another for vehicles
and i want to select from vehicles vehicle_plate_no where driver name is like driver's names text input on the form.
With bellow example i can be able to return all driver's and vehicle's information but unable to get custom information
using form text input values.

Model of vehicles table:

```
 public class vehicles extends Model{


@javax.persistence.Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
public Long Id;
public String vehicle name;
public String vehicle_plate_no;

public String created_at;
@Column(name="time", insertable=false ,columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP" )
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date time;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Drivers driver;
public static Model.Finder<Long, vehicles > findvehicles  = new 
 Finder(Long.class, vehicles.class);

public static List<vehicles> Allvehicles() {
    return findvehicles .all();

}
  }
```

Controller of vehicles table:

```
   public class AdminDashboard extends Controller {  
   public static Result DashboardResult()
     {
    Form<vehicles> result = form(vehicles.class);
    return ok(admin.render(vehicles.Allvehicles(), result));
   }
    }
```

scalla tamplete:

```
     @( formList: List[vehicles],form: Form[vehicles]) )
      @main_dashboard("Vehicle") { 
       <form  class="" role="form">
                <table width="1000" >
                    <tr>
                      <td width="500">
                          <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="automplete-1" 
              name="names"  />
                         </div>
                      </td>
                      <td width="500" >
                          <div class="form-group  col-sm-8">
                              <div class="col-lg-10">
                                  <div class='input-group date' 
                                 id='datetimepicker8'>
                              <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                               <span class="input-group-addon">
                   <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                      </span>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </td>
                      <td>
            <div class="form-group ">
   <input type='submit' class="form-control btn btn-danger" value="Find" />
                              </div>
                      </td>
                       </tr>
                </table>
                </form>
                </div>
                @for(info <- vehicles.Allvehicles()) {
           <p>@info.vehicle_plate_no</p>
           <p>@info.driver.drivername</p>    
        }
 ......................
         }
```